# How to measure/track internal link, blog to main website visit?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track all the visit that coming from blog/blog posts(site.com/blog) to the main website(site.com) or product pages(site.com/product-a), to measure which blog/content are giving value to the main site.

Currently I'm using UTM, is there any best practices or better way of doing this on Google Analytics/Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

UTMs are absolutely not a best practice in this case because you lose session continuity.
The ideal is to track everything in the same Property and use a segment that includes the sessions with blog's pages followed by pages of the institutional site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do read about not using UTM for tracking internal link here: hxxps://www.adviso.ca/en/blog/tech-en/never-never-never-tag-internal-link-external-campaign-variable-utm_campaign/

My UTM are look like these: "?utm_source=myblog&utm_medium=organic" is it still going to be a problem?

Do you mean using Sequences under Advanced on Segment?

[Sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlqWD.png)

I need to have data on which blog post are giving most traffic to the main site, is it possible to do that using Segment?